# What is the name of the default git mergetool?

Tags: git, merge

I'm wondering what the name of the default git mergetool on my linux server is?

[image]

Comment: @DopeGhoti's answer solves my issue but I also found this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309707/why-does-git-mergetool-opens-4-windows-in-vimdiff-id-expect-3

Comment: 'git config --global merge.tool' shows the currently set merge tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot provided appears to be `vimdiff`.